# Php Undefined index?

Tags: php

OK so I am making it to where when the user logs out and they try to go back to the member page it says you must be logged in to veiw this page well the echo is displaying that they must be logged in and its keeping them out but there is an error. Here is the page. it says there is a problem on line 5.

**MEMBER PHP PAGE**

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($_SESSION['username'])
    echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!<br /><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
else
    die("You must be logged in!");
?>
```

Comment: Don't delete your content, there are already two notifications that this is a duplicate. By leaving the content in its place it's easier for people who coma across this question to determine whether or not this applies to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!<br /><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
else
die("You must be logged in!");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Improve value checking for the `if` clause. I like to do an `array_key_exists` as well as a `!empty(trim())` to ensure the value is set:

```
session_start();

if (array_key_exists('username', $_SESSION)) && !empty(trim($_SESSION['username']))) {
    echo "Welcome, " . $_SESSION['username'] . "!<br /><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}
else {
    die("You must be logged in!");
}
```

Comment: what if `$_SESSION['username'] = 0` ? `empty()` check will fail.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid Undefined Index error, you can use `isset()` to check :

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && trim($_SESSION['username']) != '') {
    echo 'Welcome, ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '!<br /><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
} else {
    die("You must be logged in!");
}
```

Side note: Assuming these lines are the first few lines of the file, if you print HTML code without HTML head and body, the page is incomplete & browsers may complain about HTML structure. Suggest to have at least minimal HTML structure for every page on screen.

Comment: I generally recommend keeping PHP and HTML (or any presentation) separate with a templating setup for that very reason.  Then PHP pages don't output html, and it solves issues like malformed html structure, output before trying a headers command, etc.

Comment: Agree. However, it needs extra coding work.